# Adding text to PDF file name under specific conditions using python

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to edit file names of pdfs under specific conditions.

The names have been generated according to numbers entered into a database (non changeable) and are being referenced in another script, however, some names are followed by decimal places (543435.00, or 53838.01, and some are not (548538, 585040)  I need to add the .00 to those which dont have decimal places.

The full pdf names are presented in this format 387359_21.pdf or 33982.00_39.pdf

Is there a way to do this for a selection of files?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `os` and regular expressions `re` library in the following way:

```
import os
import re

# Split file name to append '.00' before .pdf extension
def append_suffix(filename):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
    return '{name}_{suffix}{extension}'.format(name=name, suffix='.00', ext=ext)

# Regular expression to match if filename has two digits after decimal point
regex = re.compile('[0-9]*\.[0-9]{2}')

# Loop through filenames in directory append suffix if filename doesn't match regex
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if re.search(regex, filename) is None:
        os.rename(filename, append_suffix(filename))
```

You can see how the above regular expression works here: https://regex101.com/r/aW3pR4/82